# I can't perfom my segue in navigationController in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have 4 pages.

*My first page*, I choose my provider and perform my segue for my navigationController,

*My second page*, is just my UINavigationController,

*My third page*, makes some work, and when it's over, calls this line

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainPageStat", sender: nil) //go to my last page
```

*My last page*, has a button for disconnect this account and I quit all UINaviationView with this line `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

At this point everything is working but when I want to connect again, it doesn't perform my segue at the step 3.
I put debug log just before and after,the logs are executed but not my performForSegue.

[image]

Comment: 'My third page, makes some work, and when it's over, calls this line' -> did I understand you correctly, that you implemented a VC just for a loading screen? why don't you skip the page 3 and put the loading indicator over page 4?

Comment: The third page do some ajax, request I can't do this on the page 4

Comment: How do you present these pages? By pushing them or by displaying them on top of each other as popovers?

Comment: @MauricioChirino I push them

Comment: Then you shouldn't use this `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` instruction. Instead, use `navigationController?.popController(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I can't use  `navigationController?.popController(animated: true, completion: nil)`
I want to dismiss all the view after page 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, you performing the segue in the main thread? If not move it to main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToMainPageStat", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: I'm sure, I perform the segue, because I got debug in prepareForSegue

Comment: prepareForSegue will be called irrespective of which thread you performing the segue in. Please check and confirm.